Fast reading of each cells color in an Excel sheet
Assume a piece of C# code (running in a process separate from Excel) uses Excel automation to get the used range of a worksheet, something like:
Range usedRange = theWorksheet.UsedRange;
Retrieving the content (value) of each cell may be done by:
object[,] values = usedRange.Value;
which returns the 2-dimensional object array which may be iterated locally
This works fast even from another process because number of round-trips to the COM server (Excel) is very low.
In addition to a fast retrieval of values, I also need a similar fast retrieval of formats like each cells background color, but I have not found any such simple batch-style (non-chatty) way of getting the colors.
What I have tried is to loop through each cell in usedRange and reading the associated color.
Doing this in VBA (in-process with Excel) is slow, but nothing compared to out-of-process.
A small example on my desktop:
Looping through 25000 cells in-process by VBA takes less than 0.2 seconds,
Similar looping out-of-process (by C#, I think language matters only very little) takes about 45 seconds which is about 225 times slower.
A more real case of mine involves such an iteration through perhaps 50 sheets which could take about 10 seconds in-process and more than half an hour out-of-process, the latter not acceptable.
(Actually my need is to find which cells have a given color if this helps to speed up the search).
ChatGPT urged me to read the Interior.Color of the usedRange which would return an array of colors which would be perfect (and similar to returning the values as in usedRange.Value, but ChatGPT admitted after being confronted that returning array was wrong and further dialog didn't lead to real enhancement.
Likewise, GitHub Copilot was of no help either.
Anyone out there who can share some ideas of how to overcome this problem?

Yes, CrapGPT is dumb. Interior.Color doesn't return an array at all.

"Actually my need is to find which cells have a given color if this helps to speed up the search" --> you can use Find to find a colored cell.

yeh, sure. But do you think the sheet's cells will have MANY colors, and styles? And do you definitely prefer to just have a list of the cells that have a certain interior color, or do you still want an array of all interior values?

Thanks for your help, looping with Find does the job (FindNext as continuation is not working for me, don't know why).
Actually I don't need the array of interior values, just a list of ranges, addresses or similar to identify the colored cells for later actions.
As long as this list is fairly small (which will be the normal case, perhaps maximum a few hundred spread over sheets and books) this is pretty fast, whn the number grows it is slower and slower due to the increasing number of round-trips.

Nice to hear the Find method does the job for your use-case. For reference, you can get all all the formats in one go from a usedRange, but then you have to parse XML etc, so it's not trivial - involves work on the C# side!

In order to very very quickly get the details of the formats of a large range in one go, you can read the Range.Value[11] (xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet option of the xlRangeValueDataType enum), and process the XML contained. The XML will contain all styles in the Range, as well as the Default Style.
Usual caveats apply:

Code can be better organised into patterns etc, in order to extend - can expose the XMLDoc etc
The code shown doesn't cater for when usedRange starts at a row or column > 1 - that offset needs to be done by you.
If the usedRange is massive it will fail due to memory - as will the regular Value read - so you will have to chunk backwards.

EDIT - following feedback on the need to address Styles in <Row> & <Column> - could be useful code for someone...
First step is a Basic C# handler class:
public class ExcelRangeHandler
{
readonly string NSWorkbook = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
readonly string NS_SS = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";

string RangeXML {  get; set; }
int numOfRows {  get; set; }
int numOfColumns { get; set; }

XmlDocument doc { get; set; }
XmlNamespaceManager mgr { get; set; }
SortedDictionary<int, string> columnDict {  get; set; }

private string GetAttrValue(XmlNode node, string attrname, string nSpaceURI)
{
    XmlAttribute attr = node.Attributes[attrname, nSpaceURI];
    if (attr != null) {
        return attr.Value;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

public ExcelRangeHandler(string xml)
{
    this.RangeXML = xml;

    this.doc = new XmlDocument();
    string nSpaces = "xmlns:WB='" + NSWorkbook + "' xmlns:SS='" + NS_SS + "'";
    this.mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(this.doc.NameTable);
    this.mgr.AddNamespace("WB", NSWorkbook);
    this.mgr.AddNamespace("SS", NS_SS);

    this.doc.LoadXml(this.RangeXML);

    XmlNode tableNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//WB:Table", mgr);
    numOfRows = Int32.Parse(GetAttrValue(tableNode, "ExpandedRowCount", NS_SS));
    numOfColumns = Int32.Parse(GetAttrValue(tableNode, "ExpandedColumnCount", NS_SS));

    columnDict = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
    int colCounter = 0;
    XmlNodeList columnNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//WB:Column", mgr);
    foreach (XmlNode columnNode in columnNodes)
    {
        string colIndexAttr = GetAttrValue(columnNode, "Index", NS_SS);
        colCounter = (colIndexAttr == "") ? colCounter + 1 : Int32.Parse(colIndexAttr);
        string colStyleID = GetAttrValue(columnNode, "StyleID", NS_SS);
        if (colStyleID != "")
            columnDict.Add(colCounter, colStyleID);
    }
}

private void IterateCells(Action<int, int, XmlNode, XmlNode> cellFunction, bool fillEmptyCells=true)
{
    XmlNodeList rowList = doc.SelectNodes("//WB:Row", mgr);
    int rowCounter = 0;
    foreach (XmlNode row in rowList) {
        string rowIndexAttr = GetAttrValue(row, "Index", NS_SS);
        if(rowIndexAttr != "" && fillEmptyCells) {// capture all rows between the last marked-up row & the current row
            for (int i = rowCounter + 1; i < Int32.Parse(rowIndexAttr); i++)
                for (int j = 1; j <= numOfColumns; j++)
                    cellFunction(i, j, null, null);
        }
        rowCounter = (rowIndexAttr == "") ? rowCounter + 1 : Int32.Parse(rowIndexAttr);

        XmlNodeList CellList = row.SelectNodes("./WB:Cell", mgr);
        int cellIndex = 0;

        foreach (XmlNode Cell in CellList) {
            string cellIndexAttr = GetAttrValue(Cell, "Index", NS_SS);
            if(cellIndexAttr != "" && fillEmptyCells) {//capture all the empty cells up to the marked-up cell
                for (int j = cellIndex + 1; j < Int32.Parse(cellIndexAttr); j++)
                    cellFunction(rowCounter, j, row, null);
            }
            cellIndex = (cellIndexAttr == "") ? cellIndex + 1 : Int32.Parse(cellIndexAttr);
            cellFunction(rowCounter, cellIndex, row, Cell);
        }
        if (cellIndex < numOfColumns && fillEmptyCells) {// capture all the empty cells after the last marked-up cell
            for (int j = cellIndex + 1; j<= numOfColumns; j++)
                cellFunction(rowCounter, j, row, null);
        }
    }

    if (rowCounter < numOfRows && fillEmptyCells) {// capture all rows after the last marked-up row
        for (int i = rowCounter + 1; i <= numOfRows; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j <= numOfColumns; j++)
                cellFunction(i, j, null, null);
    }
}

public Dictionary<string, string> GetDictionaryOfColors()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    //all Style elements that have an Interior Element - that have a Color attribute, then return the ID attributes
    string qs_qualStyles = "//WB:Style[WB:Interior[@SS:Color]]//@SS:ID";   
    XmlNodeList qualStyles = doc.SelectNodes(qs_qualStyles, mgr);
    Dictionary<string, string> styleDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();   

    string value;
    foreach (XmlNode qualStyle in qualStyles) {
            value = doc.SelectSingleNode("//WB:Style[@SS:ID='" + qualStyle.InnerText + "']/WB:Interior//@SS:Color", mgr)?.Value;
            styleDict.Add(qualStyle.InnerText, value);
    }
    // add the Default Style!
    value = doc.SelectSingleNode("//WB:Style[@SS:ID='Default']/WB:Interior//@SS:Color", mgr)?.Value;
    styleDict.Add("Default", value);

    string defaultColor = "";
    styleDict.TryGetValue("Default", out defaultColor);

    Action<int, int, XmlNode, XmlNode> action = (rowCounter, cellIndex, Row, Cell) =>
    {
        string RGBHexCode;
        if (Cell != null && styleDict.TryGetValue(GetAttrValue(Cell, "StyleID", NS_SS), out RGBHexCode)) {
            dict.Add("(" + rowCounter + "," + cellIndex + ")", RGBHexCode);
            return;
        }
        if (Row != null && styleDict.TryGetValue(GetAttrValue(Row, "StyleID", NS_SS), out RGBHexCode)) {
            dict.Add("(" + rowCounter + "," + cellIndex + ")", RGBHexCode);
            return;
        }
        string colID;
        if (columnDict.TryGetValue(cellIndex, out colID) && styleDict.TryGetValue(colID, out RGBHexCode))
        {
            dict.Add("(" + rowCounter + "," + cellIndex + ")", RGBHexCode);
            return;
        }
        dict.Add("(" + rowCounter + "," + cellIndex + ")", defaultColor);
    };
    IterateCells(action, true);

    return dict;            
}

public List<string> GetCellsWithColor(string RGBHexCode)
{
    List<string> cells = new List<string>();
    string qs_qualStyles = "//WB:Style[WB:Interior[@SS:Color = '" + RGBHexCode + "']]//@SS:ID";
    XmlNodeList qualStyles = doc.SelectNodes(qs_qualStyles, mgr);

    Action<int, int, XmlNode, XmlNode> action = (rowCounter, cellIndex, Row, Cell) =>
    {
        string styleID = "";
        foreach (XmlNode qualStyle in qualStyles) {
            if (Cell != null && GetAttrValue(Cell, "StyleID", NS_SS) == qualStyle.InnerText) {
                cells.Add("(" + rowCounter + "," + cellIndex + ")");
                return;
            }
            if (Row != null && GetAttrValue(Row, "StyleID", NS_SS) == qualStyle.InnerText) {
                cells.Add("(" + rowCounter + "," + cellIndex + ")");
                return;
            }
            string colID;
            if (columnDict.TryGetValue(cellIndex, out colID) && colID == qualStyle.InnerText){
                cells.Add("(" + rowCounter + "," + cellIndex + ")");
                return;
            }
        }
    };
    IterateCells(action, true);

    return cells;
}  
}

Then you would call like so:
ExcelRangeHandler handler = new ExcelRangeHandler(usedRange.Value[11]);
List<string> list = handler.GetCellsWithColor("#FFFF00");


Thanks a lot, actually I had no idea of this "parameterized property" (is it somewhat new?) which looks like an indexer on the Value property.
It seems useful and interesting indeed, however some complexities like styles defined in the Column element as well as for the Row element in addition to the Cell element, all above the default style which is not specified in the Cell element unless needed to "cancel" a style set in the corresponding Column element or Row element.

I do worry that all is not understood by me and I will probably stick to the Find method (in combination with the "normal" Value property for the values)


The Value parameter is as old as the hills, but nobody really uses it. 2. Yeh, the default style is easy to get in there, but I didn't do it for this example, as it has no fill color generally - tho of course it can be set differently

